# Want to add more column on the left side?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, pgfgantt, tikz-timing

Want to add more column on the left side?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}

\newganttchartelement*{mymilestone}{
mymilestone/.style={
shape=isosceles triangle,
inner sep=0pt,
draw=cyan,
top color=white,
bottom color=cyan!50
},
mymilestone incomplete/.style={
/pgfgantt/mymilestone,
draw=yellow,
bottom color=yellow!50
},
mymilestone label font=\slshape,
mymilestone left shift=0pt,
mymilestone right shift=0pt
}

\newgantttimeslotformat{stardate}{%
\def\decomposestardate##1.##2\relax{%
\def\stardateyear{##1}\def\stardateday{##2}%
}%
\decomposestardate#1\relax%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\stardateyear-01-01}{#2}%
\advance#2 by-1\relax%
\advance#2 by\stardateday\relax%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{1}{36}
\gantttitle{2014}{12} 
\gantttitle{2015}{12}
\gantttitle{2016}{12}\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
%First Group
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{2}{3} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{4}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{9}{12}\\
%\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
%\ganttmilestone{Milestone 1}{11}
%Second Group
\ganttgroup{Group 2}{14}{20} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{15}{18} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{18}{21} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{22}{24}\\
%\ganttlink{elem4}{elem5}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem7}
%\ganttmilestone{Milestone 1}{11}
%Third Group
\ganttgroup{Group 3}{25}{27} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{26}{28} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{28}{32} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{32}{35}
%\ganttlink{elem8}{elem9}
\ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}
\ganttlink{elem10}{elem11}
%\ganttmilestone{Milestone 1}{11}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt

Comment: @David Carlisle Is it possible to make it in LaTeX?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina need some help

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: The @-notification does only work, if the person to be notified already left a comment here ;-)

Comment: Did you investigate the `pgfgantt` package I linked to up above? If so, what specific issues do you need help with?

Comment: @Paul Gessler yea I'm still working on it but facing some problem. Like I want to close the lines on the right side and also I want to make this Schedule vertically

Comment: The outer border is drawn using the total number of months, which is determined to be 12 from your `\begin{ganttchart}[<options>]{1}{12}` line beginning the environment. You can increase 12 to 24 for two years, or 48 for four years. You already have the code to extend to 2016/2017, you just need to uncomment it. To rotate the chart, have a look at the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption). Some of them only work if you place the chart inside a `figure` environment.

Comment: @Paul Gessler need to  add more column on the left side of the sheet

Comment: @ChristianHupfer any help?

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: Sorry, I have never used `pgfgant` etc. I can not provide any help in this case